# Trying to use an IF statement in a Word table field to reference another column in the table

Tags: function, datatable, ms-word, reference

I have a three column table in a Word document. The second column has numeric values in it. The third column has text based on the value from the 2nd column. I want to use an IF statement in a function for the third column so that it displays the appropriate text, based on the value in the 2nd column. As an example for the table:

DESCRIPTION 1      value 1      text 1
DESCRIPTION 2      value 2      text 2

If value 1 is < 50, text 1 should show "below normal". If it is between 51 and 99, "normal", If it is > 99 it should show "above normal". Same thing in each row.

Based on what I found through MUCH searching I've tried everything I could think of, and I keep getting syntax errors. I created a bookmark for value 1, which I know works (I can go to it). I tried referencing the bookmark in the IF statement and I tried using the LEFT function. There must be something fundamentally wrong with how I'm coding the function. I won't bother showing you what I've tried, since I've tried about 50 different combinations of syntax.

I've done this type of thing in Excel with no problem, there's obviously something I'm just not getting when it comes to the exact syntax for the IF in Word. If I can just use the LEFT reference that would be the easiest thing to do, not sure I really even need a bookmark. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried a ridiculous number of ways of coding it and every time I get a syntax error. One of the many things I've tried - I was only testing it using a more simple IF, where it can display one of two values. This obviously doesn't fit the actual thing I'm trying to do, but I thought I'd try to do something very basic first just to get the IF to work, then expand it once I got it to work.

={IF{LEFT}=50 "YES" "NO"}

I tried doing various things - putting quotes around {LEFT}, using the bookmark name there instead of LEFT, etc. If this was Excel I would have been done a long time ago.

Comment: To see how to do this and a wide range of other calculations in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html or http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party PS: You need to have a space *after* the '='

Comment: I've gotten past the syntax errors, but it's still not working properly. I have a bookmark called srsp_a1, it's defined for one omy table cells. I know it's working, if I put my cursor somewhere else in the doc and then click on Bookmarks and tell it to GO TO that bookmark it does. Just for testing purposes I inserted a field in another cell in my table and put in the formula
 IF "{srsp_a1}">"77" "LT" "GE"    but no matter what the value of the cell with the ssrp_1 bookmark is it always evaluates to the TRUE value and shows LT.

Comment: Based on your last comment, you still haven't referenced the table cell the way the tutorial shows how to do it. You also need to ensure you're using field braces - you can't simply type the { or }.